# Name for a neutral region created by multiple states

Tags: warfare, government, map-making, cold-war

Four warring countries sign a compact to cease aggression.

The compact establishes a city to act as neutral territory for economic and foreign policy meetings. The city has an independent government for internal matters, but it's dependent on the signatories for defense, funding, and most of its population.

What term describes such a region? In other words, what geopolitical word or phrase is at the Venn diagram intersection of

1. a specific term for
2. a populated area with local autonomy, which is
3. created by more than two states?

If possible, please provide a reference to the definition of the term you suggest so that it's possible to confirm the term describes this scenario.

I've considered the following terms, but I'm not sure whether there are others that better match the criteria I've laid out above:

- buffer state
- city-state
- compact (this is not an established use of the word; this invented use would be a nod to the compact that created the region)
- protectorate
- territory

Comment: I'm VTC as the 'best answer' is based on opinion.

Comment: Note: if this gets closed or deleted here, you can ask it on [english.SE], cause a moderator [has said](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59315836#59315836) that it would most likely be on topic there.

Comment: Questions about how to name things are a poor fit for this site.

Comment: Is the name meant to be used in your story in a legal / governmental context or in common parlance?

Comment: Thanks @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica, I'll do that if needed. I'm hoping it survives here since I'm not really asking for the best term, but for people to give (and vote) their opinions on what would be good terms. We'll see.

Comment: @sphennings, I hear what you're saying. I'm hoping it fits since I'm not asking for a name per se (like "Gondor" or "Arrakis") but for peoples' opinion on geopolitical terms for this invented political structure.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan Good question. It's the formal designation as defined in the compact. If an informal or slang term's needed, I'll just make something up.

Comment: @AndyGiesler Questions asking for people's opinions are a poor fit for this site.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the question's fit. If it does get voted out, I'll find another place. But for now, I've reworded the question from "what would be a good term..." to "what term accurately describes..." Fundamentally, I'm not asking what people like the best, but what geopolitical term would accurately describe the scenario I've laid out.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! It looks like you're well on the way to this being reopened. As sphennings says, trawling for opinions isn't a good kind of question for here. If you get some good answers, please do consider a follow-up question that more narrowly focuses on the specific situation of the four warring states involved!

Comment: You're still asking for us to name a region for you. There's a lot of words that could be used to describe this region. Good questions on this site make the correct answer obvious and don't attract answers that are lists of options.

Comment: @Trioxidane, sphennings There probably is formal terminology in international law and political science for such regions, therefore this question is not "opinion based".  Voted to re-open.

Comment: The resolution, as discussed in my comment on the accepted answer: No term proposed so far exactly matches the three criteria set out in the question. However, a combination of terms can serve the purpose. An autonomous region has specificity and autonomy (criteria 1 and 2); a trust territory has specificity and multilateralism (criteria 1 and 3). Pending a fully-matching answer, for now I've accepted "autonomous territory" as being nearest in spirit, and the region will be referred to informally using the "trust territory" answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a formal term for such an entity is "autonomous region".  Since this one is created by multi-party treaty/compact, it might be referred to as "the XYZ neutral autonomous region" where XYZ is the name of the treaty.

[EDIT]  Some comments on some of the other possibilities:

- "buffer state" is the reason for its existence but not a description of what it is, in a legal sense.
- "city-state" and "territory" are unspecific.  Both descriptions apply to this entity but those terms apply to many other entities.
- "protectorate", "codominium", and some of the other suggestions implies a significant level of outside direct rulership and the querent says that it is self-governing.  The entity may have legal obligations to the nation-states that created it (e.g. neutrality, not creating a military) but those can be handled by having it be a party to the treaty or directly writing those terms into its charter/constitution.
- "DMZ" doesn't really cover this entity's being inhabited and being self-governed.

Comment: I'm grateful for everyone's suggestions. No answer quite reaches the Venn Diagram intersection clarified in the reworded question. Since I have to choose, I'm accepting yours as nearest in spirit, even though an autonomous region is normally within a single country. However, as discussed in my comment to Radovan, it's irresistable to have "trust" in the name. With nods to @Radovan and Haylen here's the plan: It's formally "The XYZ Autonomous Region" but informally (and ironically) "Trust City."

Answer (score 6):

### Condominium

No, not a posh downtown apartment close to work and the shopping district, but rather a [political condominium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condominium_(international_law)) -- a location where two or more polities share coordinated and equal dominion.

Such places do exist in reality and are places where your four warring states would exercise external control but where internal policy  could be regulated by the local authority. The specific nature of the condominium would depend on the nature of the agreement signed by the four powers. Some real world condominiums divide rule over the place by season (there is a place where for six months it is France and where for the other six months it is Spain (and where for twelve months out of the year it is *not* Andorra)).

### Demilitarized Zone

Panmunjom / Truce Village. The border between North and South Korea. Famous for being the spot where President Trump set foot on North Korean soil.

This is a place where your four powers meet but do not post troops. All their armies are kept at a discrete distance from four-corner-stone. In this scenario, the city itself governs internal affairs but remains part of the four countries politically.

### Bir Tawil

Terra Nullius. The only truly [unclaimed piece of land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Security_Area) on Earth. This is a curious piece of land whose status exists because Egypt and Sudan each have different ideas of what their mutual border should look like. In a nutshell, Egypt likes a nice clean straight border (established in 1899) and Sudan likes the administrative border (established in 1902). This means that, according to Egypt, Bir Tawil is not theirs, and according to Sudan, Bir Tawil is ... um ... not theirs ...

Just multiply the situation so that accepted borders and claims over the region leave the desired area unclaimed. [Much like Luxembourg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-WO73Dh7rY&t=9s). Being in the middle of four warring states, they won't have much choice but to accept an external defense & trade arrangement; and  because none of the four warring states claim it, its internal affairs are governed locally and can act as a neutral meeting place.

Answer (score 3):

So, much like (unworkable) [Jerusalem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_separatum_(Jerusalem)) or (functioning) [West Berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Berlin) (and somewhat less similar Danzig, Fiume, Trieste) and [UN trust territories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_trust_territories), or before that, [League of Nations mandates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_Nations_mandate) in our history? Borrowing the terminology, a *mandate* or *mandate city* or *trust city* would be a good choice; or even Free City of [city name].

Comment: As discussed in my comment to @GrumpyYoungMan, no term matched the need in all important ways, so I did my best in choosing. But as soon as I saw "Trust" I wanted to use it somehow (this is for a dystopian novel). I love the idea of people informally calling it "Trust City" and am revising the history so it's funded through a trust established by the compact's signatories. This means "Trust City" will have three meanings: a nod to the UN's trust territories, a reference to its funding source, and the irony that it's necessary because of a profound lack of trust.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I suspect this region will eventually develop three names:

- An official name based on the treaty that created it.  This is what will be used in all official international documents regarding this territory
- A semi-formal name used by each country based on how they perceive the carved out neutral zone, and tuned to their own language and ideals
- A common name/title that the new state will develop as people start making a home in the new state and it starts developing its own unique identity.  This could be a name that possibly organically develops or it could be decided upon by the new natives of this city.

Each of the three names is a nod to the worldbuilding around it, though I suspect you are looking for tips on the formal name of the territory.  The first thing is that it probably won't be officially known as a full country or state in the treaties that create it, that much is fairly obvious based on the question itself.  I also would think that what they call it will be based on the official names of the four signatories to this treaty.

In fact, the very title given to this territory could be a point of contention for the four nations due to their differing viewpoints on the matter as well as intricacies in language and official names.

A new in-world term might even be invented in-world to handle this such as a **Minor State** or **Lesser State** to denote that it has some sovereign rights but not all the rights the four signatories of the treaty have -- or any other full nations of your world for that matter.  The term **City-State** would be fairly accurate as it sounds like your four nations have carved out a city (and likely a buffer zone for said city to grow into) as the neutral territory.  It is also neutral and descriptive as to what this new territory is.

In the end, consider what the four states would like to call this city, and see if there is either a (surprising) agreement on what title to give it, or if there is a title to give it that would be acceptable to the factions involved in its creation, even if you have to make it yourself and not use something established as a term in our world.

If it helps, here is a link of [official country names](https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/official-names-of-countries).  I have noticed that most of them have Republic or Kingdom as part of their official name somewhere, but even official names are not universal.

Comment: Thanks. I used your suggestion of multiple names to round the square, since no term suggested by anyone so far has exactly matched all the criteria. (I've reworded the question to clarify the Venn diagram.) My resolution is in the comment on GrumpyYoungMan's accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

[March](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_(territory)) is such a term.  It is an independent County but where the Count is styled at the level of a Marquess.

For instance Barcelona was the seat of the [Marca Hispanica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_Hispanica), and Berlin was the capital city of the [Margraviate of Brandenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margraviate_of_Brandenburg).

Comment: A march or margavate was not an independent sovereign county.  It was a border region of one country, ruled by a more or less hereditary vassal of the ruler of that country.  The job of the ruller of a march was to protect it, and thsu te restof hte country, from attacks across the border, and to attack the people on the other side of the border.

Comment: @M.A.Golding: Words and titles are not magical; they don have the capability to affect reality. To this day, Danemark is a sovereign state... Historical sovereign states called marches/marks include Brandenburg, Moravia and Verona. (In the Holy Roman Empire they had sovereign states with all possible titles -- county, march/mark, duchy, princedom, kingdom, bishopric, archbishopric, land, etc. etc.)

Comment: @AlexP agreed but that was the basis of the question.

Comment: ? I agreed with the answer and upvoted. The comment was for M. A. Golding, giving examples of real historical sovereign states which were called marches/marks.

Comment: @M.A.Golding The way I image it, as if I were the ruler of the kingdom the March is the borderland for, (and the Marca Hispanica is the basis for my concept) is that it is beneficial to that kingdom to have an independent region, not technically part of your kingdom.  Say having the threat of Frankish defense preventing the Caliphate from advancing to the West Francia border, but also able to make an independent treaty possibly tribute or suzerainty without the West Francia having made such a treaty.

Comment: @AlexP I see how I didn't express myself.  In regards to there being a "magic word", the context of the question is about "what word to use".  The counties of England on the boarder with Scotland were discussed as being designated as Marches, but there was an uproar because that would elevate those Earls to Marquis.  So there is some power in words.

Comment: @Alex P  Denmark has been a kingdom, not a march, for over 1,000 years, so it is not really an examlple of an indieendent mark, even though mark is in its name.  And Denmark was not always an independent kingdom either, since many Danish kings were vassals for Denmakr of the Emperor.   And none of the marches in the Holy Roman Empire were independent sovereign states, they were all dependent non soverign states like territories, states, and indian tribes in the USA.

Comment: @Marlin Pierce  Actually there was an English earldom of March, or of the Welsh March 1328-30, 1348-1461, 1479-83, 1619-72, and 1675-present, held by the Duke of Richmond and Gordon.  In Scotland the earls of Dunbar, or Lothian, mostly used the title of Earl of March from 1289-1435.  There were later Scottish Earls  of March 1455-1536, 1581-1586, and 1697-present, held by the Earl of Wemyss.  There have been Marquesses in Scotland since 1599 and Marquesses in England since 1385.